# Getting an array return on function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to have this function return as an array which contains all ID (integer) from this query, but i am stuck here:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.all_id(
    prm_id integer)
    RETURNS SETOF integer 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100.0
AS $function$
DECLARE
all_id integer;
-- all_id integer[]; gives an error, while integer only returns last value
BEGIN
    SELECT id
    COLLECT INTO all_id
    FROM subject_data
    WHERE sab_subject = (
        SELECT sab_subject
        FROM subject_data
        WHERE id = prm_id
        );
        RETURN NEXT all_id;
END;
$function$;

 SELECT * FROM public.all_id(1);
```

Comment: check the example apacioje -should give you the idea, how you should refactor the code...

Comment: You want `returns int[]` instead. Also: there is no need for PL/pgSQL for this. A simple [SQL function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html) will do just fine.

Comment: `SELECT array_agg(id)
       FROM subject_data
    WHERE sab_subject = (
        SELECT sab_subject
        FROM subject_data
        WHERE id = PRM_ID_VALUE
        )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's an example of fn:

```
t=# create or replace function ar() returns int[] as $$
declare ia int[];
begin
select array_agg(oid::int) into ia from pg_database;
return ia;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
CREATE FUNCTION
t=# select * from ar();
                            ar
-----------------------------------------------------------
 {13505,16384,1,13504,16419,16816,17135,25542,25679,25723}
(1 row)
```

SETOF would return "table", language is not literal and thus does not require single quotes, [and so on](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html)...

as a_horse_with_no_name correctly brings out, you don't need plpgsql for this. A simple query will work:

```
SELECT array_agg(id) 
FROM subject_data 
WHERE sab_subject = ( 

    SELECT sab_subject 
    FROM subject_data 
    WHERE id = PRM_ID_VALUE 

)
```

Comment: You also don't need a `plpgsql` function for this. A simple SQL function will be sufficient